# C# Deserialize Two Jarray Objects in Single Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an external API that returns the response in this format:

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "columnHeadersCount": 1,
            "data": [
                [
                    "1",
                    "John",
                    "Smith",
                    "50"
                ],
                [
                    "2",
                    "Liam",
                    "Miller",
                    "10"
                ]               
            ],
            "headerOrientation": "horizontal",
            "headers": [
                [
                    {
                        "displayName": "Id"
                    },
                    {
                        "displayName": "First Name",
                        "field": "FirstNameField"
                    },
                    {
                        "displayName": "Last Name",
                        "field": "LastNameField"
                    },
                    {
                        "displayName": "Age",
                        "field": "AgeField"
                    }
                    
                ]
            ],
            "totalColumnsCount": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a Class where i want the API Response to be deserialized to

```
Student.cs    

public class Student
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how I can deserialize the response into this class given the structure of the API Response I have?

I tried to create a class called APIResponse.cs  and map the Headers and Data into JArray. Currently, I deserialize it to APIResponse.cs using this code:

> var jsonResponse =
> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.ToString());

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public JArray Data { get; set; }
    public JArray Headers { get; set; }
}
```

So I would want my Headers and Data to be deserialized in Student object.
Any thoughts? Appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: The Json looks munted. Can you paste the real payload thanks. Also that is not a valid C# class. ***Pro Tip*** try not to make people work harder the need be to read, test, and give you a solution

Comment: The given JSon data is not in correct format. Provide the correct Json data

Comment: @TheGeneral I have updated the JSON above. thanks

Comment: @Imran thanks, my bad, i have provided the correct JSON above

Comment: First off, don't do this: `[JsonProperty("First Name")]` -- that's not a valid JSON property name. It should be `[JsonProperty("firstName")]`

Comment: noted on this @Andy thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you have to follow the steps as:

**1-** Create the following classes to deserialze the data in object.

```
public class MainClass
{
    public List<Response> Responses { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public long ColumnHeadersCount { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> Data { get; set; }
    public string HeaderOrientation { get; set; }
    public List<List<Header>> Headers { get; set; }
    public long TotalColumnsCount { get; set; }
}

public class Header
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

**2-** Deserialize your Json string as below:

```
var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(YourJsonString);
```

**3-** From this `deserializedObj` you can get your Student collection:

```
var studentCollection = deserializedObj.Responses[0].Data;
```

**Updated Answer**

**4-** Get the studentCollection data in Student Type List:

```
List<Student> student = new List<Student>();
foreach(var item in studentCollection)
{
    var std = new Student()
    {
        Id = int.Parse(item[0]),
        FirstName = item[1],
        LastName = item[2],
        Age = int.Parse(item[3])
    };
    student.Add(std);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Imran this helps! Is is possible for me to have the studentCollection as List<Student>? I mean how I can deserialize it to my Student.cs because the collection has no jsonpropertyname

Comment: It can not be deserialized directly in the Student type List but after getting `studentCollection`, loop through it to get in Student type collection. Check it that I am going to update in answer.

Comment: Yep Thanks, the only caveat I see if I loop on the studentCollection is when I have large dataset, >5000 items.

Comment: Yep for large data-set it might be costly but you have to bear it because of receiving Json format.